# Creating a Angular2 TS app in a Cordova project

Tags: angularjs, node.js, cordova, angular, typescript

I thought to myself, I should leverage the best of Angular, Angular 2 TS and cordova to get my web application up and running.  Not a bad idea to think of, but I was having some minor issues.  I wasn't sure if anyone had them, or knows how to implement them.  I noticed there are next to no how-tos online and you end up when searching for *angular 2 cordova* you actually get results for a different mobile web framework.

So first thing I did was execute these scripts.

```
mkdir myApp
cd myApp
cordova create .
cordova platform add android browser
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-browsersync
```

the browser sync i thought would be necessary to handle the fact I am no longer using server-lite in the angular2 application which has browser sync.  More to come later.

```
cd www
rm /f /r *    #or equivalent.  I deleted the contents.
```

This is where I start the Angular 2 TS how-to via: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html

```
#create 4 files:  package.json, systemjs.config.js, tsconfig.json, typings.json
```

Now this is where I do some modifications.  Since we are using Cordova and Not server-light, i went into the package.json and updated the npm start script to: `"start": "tsc && concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"cordova run browser --live-reload\" ",`.  The reason as I stated is that it was `server-lite` but we are using cordova.  Since cordova itself doesnt do a live refresh, I installed the plugin *cordova-plugin-browsersync* you can read up on it here: https://github.com/nparashuram/cordova-plugin-browsersync

```
npm install
npm typings install
mkdir app
#make ts files.
cd ..
#make html / css file.
```

Now, Everything is in place, i created everything for Angular 2 in `[cordovaProj]/www` and i want to now run it.

```
npm start
```

it will compile everything and run the cordova server. AWESOME. IT WORKS.... or so i thought.  It doesn't refresh.

Test 1: Change index.html file..  Change the contents of title.

Result 1:  No live update.

Test 2: Change the result of `www/app/app.component.ts` template to say: **Hello World**.

Result 2:  tsc-w fires, updates everything as angular does.  Browser doesnt refresh.

Observations:  When I run `npm start` i noticed 1 thing, even though it is saying to run `cordova run browser --live-reload` it ends up running `cordova run --nobuild`

Here is the console output i scraped:

```js
C:\Users\wfrancis\WebstormProjects\SampleCordovaAngular2Application\www\app>npm
start

> angular-quickstart@1.0.0 start C:\Users\wfrancis\WebstormProjects\SampleCordov
aAngular2Application\www
> tsc && concurrently "npm run tsc:w" "cordova run browser --live-reload"

[0]
[0] > angular-quickstart@1.0.0 tsc:w C:\Users\wfrancis\WebstormProjects\SampleCo
rdovaAngular2Application\www
[0] > tsc -w
[0]
[0] 9:38:35 AM - Compilation complete. Watching for file changes.
[1] Running command: cmd "/s /c "C:\Users\wfrancis\WebstormProjects\SampleCordov
aAngular2Application\platforms\browser\cordova\build.bat""
[1]
[1] Cleaning Browser project
[1] Running command: cmd "/s /c "C:\Users\wfrancis\WebstormProjects\SampleCordov
aAngular2Application\platforms\browser\cordova\run.bat --nobuild""
[1]
[1] Static file server running @ http://localhost:8000/index.html
[1] CTRL + C to shut down
[1] 200 /index.html
[1] 200 /styles.css
[1] 200 /systemjs.config.js (gzip)
[1] 200 /node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js (gzip)
[1] 200 /node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js (gzip)
[1] 200 /node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js (gzip)
[1] 200 /node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js (gzip)
[1] 200 /app/main.js
[1] 404 /favicon.ico
[1] 200 /node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser
-dynamic.umd.js (gzip)
[1] 200 /app/app.module.js (gzip)
[1] 200 /app/app.component.js (gzip)
[1] 200 /node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js (gzip)
[1] 200 /node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js
(gzip)
[1] 200 /node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js (gzip)
[1] 200 /node_modules/@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js (gzip)
[1] 200 /node_modules/rxjs/Subject.js (gzip)
[1] 200 /node_modules/rxjs/Observable.js (gzip)
[1] 200 /node_modules/rxjs/Subscriber.js (gzip)
[1] 200 /node_modules/rxjs/util/ObjectUnsubscribedError.js
[1] 200 /node_modules/rxjs/Subscription.js (gzip)
[1] 200 /node_modules/rxjs/symbol/rxSubscriber.js
[1] 200 /node_modules/rxjs/SubjectSubscription.js (gzip)
[1] 200 /node_modules/rxjs/util/root.js
[1] 200 /node_modules/rxjs/util/toSubscriber.js
[1] 200 /node_modules/rxjs/symbol/observable.js
[1] 200 /node_modules/rxjs/util/isFunction.js
[1] 200 /node_modules/rxjs/Observer.js
[1] 200 /node_modules/rxjs/util/isArray.js
[1] 200 /node_modules/rxjs/util/isObject.js
[1] 200 /node_modules/rxjs/util/tryCatch.js
[1] 200 /node_modules/rxjs/util/errorObject.js
[1] 200 /node_modules/rxjs/util/UnsubscriptionError.js (gzip)
```

I noticed on the github for browsersync, it said to do: `cordova run -- --live-reload` but the first set of *--* i thought meant to be whatever platform you were running, in my case `browser`

Test 3:  Used: `cordova run -- --live-reload` instead of `cordova run browser --live-reload`, called npm start (printout below), and attempted to change HTML.

Result 3:  No update.

Test 4: same as Test 3, but attempted to change `www/app/app.component.ts` and noticed that a change was watched, and the new JS was compiled.  Still no update to application.

```js
C:\Users\wfrancis\WebstormProjects\SampleCordovaAngular2Application\www\app>npm
start

> angular-quickstart@1.0.0 start C:\Users\wfrancis\WebstormProjects\SampleCordov
aAngular2Application\www
> tsc && concurrently "npm run tsc:w" "cordova run -- --live-reload"

[0]
[0] > angular-quickstart@1.0.0 tsc:w C:\Users\wfrancis\WebstormProjects\SampleCo
rdovaAngular2Application\www
[0] > tsc -w
[0]
[0] 9:56:33 AM - Compilation complete. Watching for file changes.
[1] Running command: cmd "/s /c "C:\Users\wfrancis\WebstormProjects\SampleCordov
aAngular2Application\platforms\browser\cordova\build.bat --live-reload""
[1]
[1] Cleaning Browser project
[1] [BS] Access URLs:
[1]  -------------------------------------
[1]        Local: http://localhost:3000
[1]     External: http://10.224.60.17:3000
[1]  -------------------------------------
[1]           UI: http://localhost:3001
[1]  UI External: http://10.224.60.17:3001
[1]  -------------------------------------
[1] [BS] Serving files from: platforms\android\assets\www
[1] [BS] Serving files from: platforms\ios\www
[1] [BS] Watching files...
[1] ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\wfrancis\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
[1] JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_77
[1] Starting a new Gradle Daemon for this build (subsequent builds will be faste
r).
[1] Incremental java compilation is an incubating feature.
[1] :preBuild UP-TO-DATE
[1] :preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
[1] :checkDebugManifest
[1] :CordovaLib:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
[1] :CordovaLib:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
[1] :CordovaLib:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
[1] :CordovaLib:compileLint
[1]
[1] :CordovaLib:copyDebugLint UP-TO-DATE
[1] :CordovaLib:mergeDebugProguardFiles
[1]
[1] :CordovaLib:packageDebugRenderscript
[1]  UP-TO-DATE
[1] :CordovaLib:checkDebugManifest
[1] :CordovaLib:prepareDebugDependencies
[1] :CordovaLib:compileDebugRenderscript
[1]
[1] :CordovaLib:generateDebugResValues
[1]
[1] :CordovaLib:generateDebugResources
[1] :CordovaLib:packageDebugResources
[1]
[1] :CordovaLib:compileDebugAidl
[1]
[1] :CordovaLib:generateDebugBuildConfig
[1]
[1] :CordovaLib:mergeDebugShaders
[1]
[1] :CordovaLib:compileDebugShaders
[1]
[1] :CordovaLib:generateDebugAssets
[1]
[1] :CordovaLib:mergeDebugAssets
[1]
[1] :CordovaLib:processDebugManifest
[1]
[1] :CordovaLib:processDebugResources
[1]
[1] :CordovaLib:generateDebugSources
[1] :CordovaLib:incrementalDebugJavaCompilationSafeguard
[1]
[1] :CordovaLib:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
[1]
[1] :CordovaLib:compileDebugJavaWithJavac - is not incremental (e.g. outputs hav
e changed, no previous execution, etc.).
[1] Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
[1] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
[1] :CordovaLib:processDebugJavaRes
[1]  UP-TO-DATE
[1] :CordovaLib:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug
[1]
[1] :CordovaLib:transformClassesAndResourcesWithSyncLibJarsForDebug
[1]
[1] :CordovaLib:mergeDebugJniLibFolders
[1]
[1] :CordovaLib:transformNative_libsWithMergeJniLibsForDebug
[1]
[1] :CordovaLib:transformNative_libsWithSyncJniLibsForDebug
[1]
[1] :CordovaLib:bundleDebug
[1]
[1] :prepareAndroidCordovaLibUnspecifiedDebugLibrary
[1]
[1] :prepareDebugDependencies
[1] :compileDebugAidl
[1]
[1] :compileDebugRenderscript
[1]
[1] :generateDebugBuildConfig
[1]
[1] :mergeDebugShaders
[1]
[1] :compileDebugShaders
[1]
[1] :generateDebugAssets
[1] :mergeDebugAssets
[1] Running command: cmd "/s /c "C:\Users\wfrancis\WebstormProjects\SampleCordov
aAngular2Application\platforms\browser\cordova\run.bat --nobuild --live-reload""

[1]
[1] Static file server running @ http://localhost:8000/index.html
[1] CTRL + C to shut down
[1] 200 /index.html
[1] 200 /styles.css
[1] 200 /systemjs.config.js (gzip)
[1] 200 /node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js (gzip)
[1] 200 /node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js (gzip)
[1] 200 /node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js (gzip)
[1] 200 /node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js (gzip)
[1] 200 /app/main.js
[1] 200 /node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser
-dynamic.umd.js (gzip)
[1] 200 /app/app.module.js (gzip)
[1] 200 /app/app.component.js (gzip)
[1] 200 /node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js
(gzip)
[1] 200 /node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js (gzip)
[1] 200 /node_modules/@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js (gzip)
[1] 200 /node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js (gzip)
[1] 200 /node_modules/rxjs/Subject.js (gzip)
[1] 200 /node_modules/rxjs/Observable.js (gzip)
[1] 200 /node_modules/rxjs/util/ObjectUnsubscribedError.js
[1] 200 /node_modules/rxjs/util/root.js
[1] 200 /node_modules/rxjs/symbol/rxSubscriber.js
[1] 200 /node_modules/rxjs/Subscriber.js (gzip)
[1] 200 /node_modules/rxjs/Subscription.js (gzip)
[1] 200 /node_modules/rxjs/SubjectSubscription.js (gzip)
[1] 200 /node_modules/rxjs/util/toSubscriber.js
[1] 200 /node_modules/rxjs/symbol/observable.js
[1] 200 /node_modules/rxjs/util/isFunction.js
[1] 200 /node_modules/rxjs/Observer.js
[1] 200 /node_modules/rxjs/util/isArray.js
[1] 200 /node_modules/rxjs/util/isObject.js
[1] 200 /node_modules/rxjs/util/tryCatch.js
[1] 200 /node_modules/rxjs/util/errorObject.js
[1] 200 /node_modules/rxjs/util/UnsubscriptionError.js (gzip)
```

Does anyone have a way in which I could get a Live Update for the Browser?  This is a critical piece for development, and waiting a few minutes for it to run through `npm start` is too much.

*EDIT*  I noticed a update that was very much so delayed.  Result 4 gave me this printout:

```js
[0] 10:03:47 AM - File change detected. Starting incremental compilation...
[0] 10:03:49 AM - Compilation complete. Watching for file changes.
[1] [BS] Reloading Browsers...
[1] [BS] Reloading Browsers...
[1]
[1] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
[1]
[1] * What went wrong:
[1] Execution failed for task ':mergeDebugAssets'.
[1] > Error: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\wfrancis\WebstormProjects\S
ampleCordovaAngular2Application\platforms\android\assets\www\node_modules\lite-s
erver\node_modules\browser-sync\node_modules\bs-recipes\recipes\grunt.html.injec
tion\app\browser-sync-start.html (The system cannot find the file specified)
[1]
[1] * Try:
[1] Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --de
bug option to get more log output.
[1]
[1] Error: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\wfrancis\WebstormProjects\Sam
pleCordovaAngular2Application\platforms\android\assets\www\node_modules\lite-ser
ver\node_modules\browser-sync\node_modules\bs-recipes\recipes\grunt.html.injecti
on\app\browser-sync-start.html (The system cannot find the file specified)
[1] :mergeDebugAssets FAILED
[1]
[1] BUILD FAILED
[1]
[1] Total time: 3 mins 12.839 secs
[1]
[1] * What went wrong:
[1] Execution failed for task ':mergeDebugAssets'.
[1] > Error: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\wfrancis\WebstormProjects\S
ampleCordovaAngular2Application\platforms\android\assets\www\node_modules\lite-s
erver\node_modules\browser-sync\node_modules\bs-recipes\recipes\grunt.html.injec
tion\app\browser-sync-start.html (The system cannot find the file specified)
[1]
[1] * Try:
[1] Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --de
bug option to get more log output.
[1]
```

Comment: You need to make sure your templates are being overwritten, if you delete everything out of the `www` folder, does your next ionic serve cause stuff to work?

Comment: I saw ionic, but i wasnt sure what that was about, and didnt leverage it.  I was not sure if it was needed, since this was my first approach, I thought i could get around the need for anything else  It did do what it needed though, the inital run launched the application and it ran, but it did not do any browser refreshes on edit of both an html file and the app component ts file.

Comment: Sorry, I thought you were using Ionic2 since it leverages Angular, includes a good library of UI widgets, and makes the whole experience of developing cordova apps much cleaner.  My previous remark still stands, if you clean out your WWW folder and re-build, what happens?

Comment: clean out in what regard, other than making edits in the angular 2 app which is in www/ I havent done anything, is there a command you would want me to test within the underlying Angular content?   *I noticed that when running the app with 2 platforms, it seems like it will error out on the android build.*

Comment: I will do a quick tutorial with Ionic and see how that works. Maybe Ionic would be the Course of Action I would need to take if i were to leverageangular 2 with cordova.